# Showing only the top 5 results

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system, view

Sorry, I'm rubbish at php but I am willing to learn.

I'm creating my website found [here](http://www.xclo.mobi/xclo2)

and am creating a page called [more](http://www.xclo.mobi/xclo2/more.php).

Within this page I want to add a list of my top 5 promotions on my site. Each promotion is saved in my mobi database in mysql and I have added a count for each time someone views a particular promotion on my single.php page.

So basically. What I need to do is display 5 promotions with the highest number in the "views" field in my mobi database.

I currently have these codes:

```
include_once('include/connection.php');
include_once('include/article.php');
```

and

```
<?php foreach ($articles as $article) { ?>

<a href="list.php?id=<?php echo $article['promo_title']; ?>"> <?php echo $article['promo_title']; ?> </a>
```

in more.php and also

```
class views {
public function fetch_all(){
   global $pdo;

 $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM mobi ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 0, 5");
   $query->execute();

return $query->fetch(); 

}

}
```

in articles.php which only loads some weird text of "t t t t h h w w d d d d 3 3"

I think I need to ad an array of some sort but I'm not sure how to type it.

Please can someone advise me on how?

thank you.

Comment: You call your function `fetch_all`, so why are you calling `$query->fetch()` and not `$query->fetchAll()`?

Comment: Where do you set `$articles`? What do you see if you `var_dump($articles)`?

Comment: indeed, $query->fetch() only gets you the first row.
i think the problem might be in article.php (or where ever you convert your query results into the $articles array)

Comment: where is the closing bracket of your foreach loop?

Comment: Barmer. You are correct. changing it from fetch to fetchAll works. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fetch() should be changed to fetchAll()

```
 class views
 {
    public function fetch_all()
    {
      global $pdo;

      $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM mobi ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 0, 5");
      $query->execute();

      return $query->fetchAll(); 

    }
 }
```

and foreach closing bracket should also be added

```
<?php foreach ($articles as $article) { ?>

<a href="list.php?id=<?php echo $article['promo_title']; ?>">
<?php echo $article['promo_title']; ?> </a>
 <?php } ?>
```

And also check the code where you are returning the result set and sending it to the article.php

Comment: @KevHopwood if the response was helpful and solved your problem, make sure to approve the answer so the poster gets some credit for the time they spent helping you out.